# How to sum multiple values from different tables

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a query to get all data (for the general, obtain the ten first values, using limit and offset). The problem shows up when the front request wants to show the data for the first time, and these always don't need a filter.

The next query is using a where

```
select 'act' as type, c.crop_id, f.farm_name, l.lot_name, c.crop_name, 
coalesce(c.crop_real_plants::integer, 0) as real_plants, l.lot_area, c.crop_invest, 
am.actmach_id, sum(am.actmach_cost)
from crops c 
inner join lots l on c.lot_id = l.lot_id 
inner join farms f on l.farm_id = f.farm_id 
inner join activities a on c.crop_id = a.crop_id 
inner join activities_machines am on a.activity_id = am.activity_id 
where c.crop_id = 3
group by c.crop_id , f.farm_name , l.lot_name , c.crop_name , l.lot_area , c.crop_invest , am.actmach_id 
union 
select 'act' as type, c.crop_id, f.farm_name, l.lot_name, c.crop_name, 
coalesce(c.crop_real_plants::integer, 0) as real_plants, l.lot_area, c.crop_invest, 
ap.actpay_id , sum(ap.actpay_cost) 
from crops c 
inner join lots l on c.lot_id = l.lot_id 
inner join farms f on l.farm_id = f.farm_id 
inner join activities a on c.crop_id = a.crop_id 
inner join activities_payrolls ap on a.activity_id = ap.actpay_id 
where c.crop_id = 3
group by c.crop_id , f.farm_name , l.lot_name , c.crop_name , l.lot_area , c.crop_invest , ap.actpay_id 
union 
select 'act', c.crop_id, f.farm_name, l.lot_name, c.crop_name, 
coalesce(c.crop_real_plants::integer, 0) as real_plants, l.lot_area, c.crop_invest, 
asp.actsup_id, sum(asp.actsup_cost) 
from crops c 
inner join lots l on c.lot_id = l.lot_id 
inner join farms f on l.farm_id = f.farm_id 
inner join activities a on c.crop_id = a.crop_id 
inner join activities_supplies asp on a.activity_id = asp.actsup_id 
where c.crop_id = 3
group by c.crop_id , f.farm_name , l.lot_name , c.crop_name , l.lot_area , c.crop_invest , asp.actsup_id 
union 
select 'cost', c.crop_id, f.farm_name, l.lot_name, c.crop_name, 
coalesce(c.crop_real_plants::integer, 0) as real_plants, l.lot_area, c.crop_invest, 
cd.cost_detail_id, sum(cd.cost_detail_value) 
from crops c 
inner join lots l on c.lot_id = l.lot_id 
inner join farms f on l.farm_id = f.farm_id 
inner join costs_details cd on c.crop_id = cd.crop_id 
where c.crop_id = 3
group by c.crop_id , f.farm_name , l.lot_name , c.crop_name , l.lot_area , c.crop_invest , cd.cost_detail_id 
union 
select 'prod', c.crop_id, f.farm_name, l.lot_name, c.crop_name, 
coalesce(c.crop_real_plants::integer, 0) as real_plants, l.lot_area, c.crop_invest, 
pc.category_id, sum(pc.category_price) 
from crops c 
inner join lots l on c.lot_id = l.lot_id 
inner join farms f on l.farm_id = f.farm_id 
inner join productions p on c.crop_id = p.crop_id 
inner join production_categories pc on p.production_id = pc.category_production
where c.crop_id = 3
group by c.crop_id , f.farm_name , l.lot_name , c.crop_name , l.lot_area , c.crop_invest , pc.category_id;
```

The result is:

[image: result using where]

The idea is to get the consolidated values of each `type`. If we take the results of the image, should be the next:

- act `sum(30000 + 6000)`
- prod `sum(500000 + 2)`
- cost `sum(66666.67 + 133333.33 + 33333.33 + 93333.33)`

I hope to get the **sum values**, and use the next formulas:

- crop_invest / lot_area
- activities_consolidate / crop_real_plants
- activities_consolidate / productions_consolidate

Comment: Provide sample data as online fiddle or as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts (screenshot is not useful). Show desired output for this data, add explanations.

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to add query result, right now

Comment: @Akina I change the content, could you see the question?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, exactly. Please show your desired result. And clarify the part about `LIMIT` / `OFFSET`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetterHi friend, I put into the content question the plus operations I will hope to get

Comment: your question is VERY difficult to read, maybe ask a small section at a time